# Have Pycharm run inspections only on the code that changed since a commit

Tags: python, pycharm

I've been using Pycharm for a few years now, but it has always been a bit laggy and a bit of a resource hog. I was wondering if anyone knows a way to have Pycharm run inspections only on the code that would come up in a git-diff. I am working in a large code-base with large files, and I don't need all that inspection.

Answer (score 0):

From the jetbrains documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/running-inspections.html

What you seem to want to do is change the scope of the inspections that are run. In the settings menu if you go to Code Style > Inspections and select a category (e.g. General, or Python) you may select something like "Changed Files" to only run inspections on uncommitted files for that category.